# showing that all convex polehedron graphs are 3-connected

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, polyhedra, polytopes

I'm trying to figure out how to show that two nonadjacent vertices in the graph of a convex polyhedron can be disconnected from one another by the removal of at least three vertices.

I know what a convex polyhedron is (I at least have a clear picture in my head of what they look like), and it is clear that they are planar, but I can't quite characterize them to even begin to prove this. I want to try assuming that the removal of two vertices would disconnect two nonadjacent vertices, but I can't see what to do from there. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The edge-vertex graphs of some 3-dimensional convex polytopes are more than 3-connected. For example the regular icosahedron's graph is 5-connected. One approach to 3-connectedness is to say that every pair of distinct vertices u and v can be joined by at least 3 paths whose only vertices in common are u and v. On the icosahedron for any pair of distinct vertices there are 5 such paths so the icosahedron is 5-connected.

Comment: @JosephMalkevitch Thank you for that example. You are right, the icosahedron graph is 5-connected. Then I am confused by the statement I have been asked to prove..  It says: "For the graph of a convex polehedron show that any two nonadjacent vertices are separated by at least three others." Your example is a counterexample, is it not? Unless I am not understanding what the author means by "separated"...

Comment: @JosephMalkevitch This question is from Tutte's graph theory book, by the way.

Comment: Tutte tended to use somewhat different terminology from some other authors, and I don't know his definitions here. The now "standard" approach to Steinitz's Theorem: A graph is 3-polytopal if and only if it is 3-connected is described in the books of polytopes by Grünbaum and Ziegler. Their approach allows graphs to be 4 or 5-connected but also 3-connected. Some 3-connected graphs are not 4-connected or 5-connected. The only proof I know of that 3-polytopes are 3-connected uses a theorem of M. Balinksi that the graphs of d-polytopes are d-connected.

Comment: Typo in above in my statement of Steinitz's Theorem: A graph is 3-polytopal if and only it is planar and 3-connected.

Answer (score 1):

An n-polyhedral graph (sometimes called a c-net) is a 3-connected simple planar graph on n nodes. Every convex polyhedron can be represented in the plane or on the surface of a sphere by a 3-connected planar graph. Conversely, every 3-connected planar graph can be realized as a convex polyhedron. Polyhedral graphs are sometimes simply known as "polyhedra" (which is rather confusing since the term "polyhedron" more commonly refers to a solid with n faces, not n vertices).
Through duality, each polyhedral graph on $V=n$ nodes corresponds to a graph with F=n faces. So the polyhedral graphs on n nodes are isomorphic to the convex polyhedra with n faces.  The icosahedral graph with $12$ vertices is 5-connected and corresponds to the dodecahedron, a convex polyhedron with $12$ faces which is 3-connected. In every case either the polyhedral graph or its planar dual would be 3-connected.